# OpenGL ES 2 Console Framebuffer Cursor

Tags: linux, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I'm creating a very simple OpenGL ES 2.0 demo that runs on a Yocto Linux distribution on an iMX6 core.  I'm writing the image direct to the console frame buffer, as opposed to using X11.  I use the Vivante GPU drivers that implement EGL.

When I run the app, I see the cursor flashing away at the bottom of the screen and if I type during the program execution, the letters appear at the bottom.  How do I stop this happening as part of the program?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.arm.kernel/10358).

The answer suggested doing this, which also removes power management:

```
#include <linux/kd.h>

int cfd;

// Set console to graphics mode
if((cfd=open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR))<0){
  fprintf(stderr, "Error - cannot open tty0\n");
  return -1;
}
else{
  ioctl(cfd, KDSETMODE, KD_GRAPHICS);
}
```

I needed to add two further includes, `<fnctl.h>` and `<sys/ioctl.h>`.

Warning - if your program doesn't have a means of exiting, then this will disable your ability to stop the program by pressing `CTRL C`.